# Android App OKHTTP Websocket onFailure() connection close when Switch.setChecked(true) called

Tags: android, android-layout, https, websocket

I am developing a websocket app in android studio emulator, and apparently everything works fine, until the program execute "Switch.setChecked(true)".
When program execute "Switch.setChecked(true)", the "public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response)" method are called and connection close.

I thought it was some recursion problem in the listener, but if the "onCheckedChanged()" function inside listener doesn't have any code, the problem still persists.

NOTE:
I am using https/wss.
The secure websocket server it's being programmed by me in esp32.

Thank's for the help.

```
private Switch lampSwitch;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{  
    ...

    lampSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.lampSwitch);
    lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new lampSwitchListener());

    ...
}


private static final String TAG = "FragmentActivity";
private String sendValue;

private class lampSwitchListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: test");

        if (isChecked)
        {
            sendValue = "{\"lamp\":\"ON\"}";
        }
        else
        {
            sendValue = "{\"lamp\":\"OFF\"}";
        }
        send_Ws_Message(2, sendValue);
    }
}


private void process_Message( ByteString input )    
{
    ByteString b = input.substring(1);    // offset 1 position.
    String message = b.utf8();    // convert from ByteString to String.
    

    Log.d("MSG: ", message);
    Log.d("length: ", String.valueOf(message.length() ) );
    
    
    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try
    {
        jObject = new JSONObject(message);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String lamp = null;
    try
    {
        lamp = jObject.getString("lamp");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if ( lamp.equals("ON") )
    {
        Log.d("lamp: ", lamp);
        Log.d("lamp.length: ", String.valueOf(lamp.length() ));


        lampSwitch.setChecked(true);    // this code line close client websocket connection
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2020-10-03 00:37:44.898 6218-6218/? I/mple.myfirstap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-10-03 00:37:44.914 6218-6218/? I/mple.myfirstap: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2020-10-03 00:37:44.915 6218-6218/? W/mple.myfirstap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-10-03 00:37:45.070 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
2020-10-03 00:37:45.072 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
2020-10-03 00:37:45.082 6218-6243/com.example.myfirstapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-10-03 00:37:45.088 6218-6243/com.example.myfirstapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-10-03 00:37:45.092 6218-6243/com.example.myfirstapp D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-10-03 00:37:45.201 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp W/mple.myfirstap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-10-03 00:37:45.201 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp W/mple.myfirstap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-10-03 00:37:45.295 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xee254710, tid 6241
2020-10-03 00:37:45.299 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-10-03 00:37:45.301 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-10-03 00:37:45.306 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xee064eb0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-10-03 00:37:45.323 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xee064eb0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xee3b5630) (first time)
2020-10-03 00:37:45.343 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2020-10-03 00:37:45.344 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-10-03 00:37:45.344 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xee253ed0, tid 6241
2020-10-03 00:37:45.369 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2020-10-03 00:37:45.369 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fc7ba000 size 0x2000
2020-10-03 00:37:45.375 6218-6241/com.example.myfirstapp D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-10-03 00:37:47.795 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp W/mple.myfirstap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2020-10-03 00:37:47.797 6218-6218/com.example.myfirstapp E/TypefaceCompatApi26Impl: Unable to collect necessary methods for class java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.graphics.FontFamily.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.obtainFontFamilyCtor(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:321)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi26Impl.java:84)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.<init>(TypefaceCompatApi28Impl.java:36)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.<clinit>(TypefaceCompat.java:47)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:705)
        at android.widget.TextView.resolveStyleAndSetTypeface(TextView.java:2183)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTypefaceFromAttrs(TextView.java:2154)
        at android.widget.TextView.applyTextAppearance(TextView.java:4105)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1630)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:99)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:163)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-10-03 00:37:49.599 6218-6251/com.example.myfirstapp D/FragmentActivity: onFailure: caca
```

Comment: It's phrased as a websocket question refering okhttp, but with a logcat with what looks like a very fatal font related error.

Comment: By the tests i did, the problem is not related with the OkHttp lib. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved with:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener( null );
        lampSwitch.setChecked(true);
        lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new lampSwitchListener());
    }
});
```

The strange thing is that only the Switch widget needs it, the SeekBar widget didn’t, but I used "runOnUiThread" anyway in SeekBar too.

Answer (score 0):

By the tests i did, the problem is not related with the OkHttp lib.

I have a seekbBar on my app too and i tested with only the seekBar and worked.

```
slider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.slider);
slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new sliderListener());
```

I found that Switch in this way it works correctly, ie: change the Switch state on screen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    lampSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.lampSwitch);
    lampSwitch.setChecked(true);
    lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new lampSwitchListener());

    ...
```

I found that Switch in this way crash the app, ie: app close.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    lampSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.lampSwitch);
    lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new lampSwitchListener());
    lampSwitch.setChecked(true);    

    ...
```

I already tryied the code below but not worked too.
Here the websocket connection close and the Switch state on screen don't change.
I tested with another Switch in the app and the same behavior.

```
if ( lamp.equals("ON") )
{
    Log.d("lamp: ", lamp);
    Log.d("lamp.length: ", String.valueOf(lamp.length() ) );

    lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener( null );
    lampSwitch.setChecked(true);    
    lampSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new lampSwitchListener());
}
```

Any suggestion is very welcome.